# How to store specific tags in database

Tags: php, sql, database

I read lots of posts about tags but none seem to do what I am doing.
I have this post uploader where you have 6 tags from which you can choose as many as you want by clicking the check boxes beside each category and that POSTs the value to the php.

All that's fine, I just don't get how to store the tags in the database.
If somebody uploads something that has to do with 4 categories I will have 4 tag variables which I will insert into somewhere. What's the best method to store the tags so I can sort the posts by tags into different pages later?

EDIT:

The HTML of the category checkboxes is something like this:

```
<ul class="selectionList">
    <li>
        <div class="markerDiv"  id="maker_school">
            <input class="marker_ckeckbox" name="markerType" value="Naruto" type="checkbox"  /> 
            <label class="marker_label">Naruto</label> 
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="markerDiv"  id="maker_school">
            <input class="marker_ckeckbox" name="markerType" value="OnePiece" type="checkbox"  /> 
            <label class="marker_label">One Piece</label> 
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="markerDiv"  id="maker_school">
            <input class="marker_ckeckbox" name="markerType" value="DragonBall" type="checkbox"  /> 
            <label class="marker_label">Dragon Ball</label> 
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="markerDiv"  id="maker_school">
            <input class="marker_ckeckbox" name="markerType" value="Facts" type="checkbox"  /> 
            <label class="marker_label">Facts</label> 
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
         <div class="markerDiv"  id="maker_school">
            <input class="marker_ckeckbox" name="markerType" value="Quotes" type="checkbox"  /> 
            <label class="marker_label">Quotes</label> 
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="markerDiv"  id="maker_school">
            <input class="marker_ckeckbox" name="markerType" value="Other" type="checkbox"  /> 
            <label class="marker_label">Other</label> 
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I was thinking of grabbing $tag1,2...6 from POST['tag1']['name'] etc. then check if any of them are different to nothing else echo no category selected. Inside the if statement though I was thinking of inserting the t.id of the tag whose name is $tag1,2,3...6 and the postid of the post that is being uploaded into post_tags?

I know how to write it in php, but I just wanna know if the thought process is correct.

Answer (score 1):

That is called a *n to m relation*. You can map it like this

```
posts table
-----------
id
title
...


tags table
----------
id
name
...


post_tags table
---------------
post_id
tag_id
```

To get all tags of a specific post you can do

```
select t.name
from tags t
join post_tags pt on pt.tag_id = t.id
join posts p on pt.post_id = p.id
where p.title = 'my little post'
```

Comment: ahaa, I get that part, what I don't get is how will I grab the values and where will I insert them? I updated the question with some html and a speculation of how I would do it if you could check it out, thanks.